# compare input value with value in database coldfusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coldfusion

I have 5 textboxes(`cfinput`) on my form to enter organisation code. What I want to do is, As the user types the Org code, there should be an `onkeyup` function that will validate the value with all the values in database and if its invalid it should show "Invalid Code."
I have got all the Org codes in an array called `OrgIndexArray`. I am not getting, how would I do this for all the 5 textboxes (some sort of `cfloop`?)

```
<cfquery name="getOrgCodes" datasource="#sqlDS#">
    select distinct OrgCode From #SAUserIndex#
</cfquery>

<cfset IndexCodesList = ValueList(getOrgCodes.OrgCode)>
<cfset IndexCodesArray = #ListToArray(IndexCodesList)#>

<script>
    var IndexArray=<cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(getOrgCodes,true)# </cfoutput>
    $(document).ready(fucntion() {
        $('.IndexCodes').on('keyup',function(){
           if(!!~jQuery.inArray($this.val(),IndexArray)) {
               document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Invalid Index";
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: When you say you have the values in an array, is this a coldfusion array? or a javascript array?

Comment: @JanR Its a coldfusion array.

Comment: Do these 5 text boxes take one character each?  If not, using onkeyup to trigger js functions might be somewhat unwise.  Next, if you have all the codes in a CF array, you can use the toScript function to convert that array to a JS array.  Finally, if you are getting all the available codes anyway, why not use a select control instead of textboxes?

Comment: I have inserted the code now. I guess this shall make it more clear to understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: @DanBracuk These 5 textboxes takes 5 characters. I have posted the code above, this might give an idea of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: It appears that the user has to type all 25 characters before they even have a chance of getting it right?  And, if they get one character wrong they don't know which one?  That's how I interpret the code sample. If my interpretation is correct, I have to ask whether or not you have a good plan.  As far as your attempt goes, try to work with smaller sample sizes.  I would probably start by changing my query to select just the 1st character of each code and develop my js from that.

Comment: @DanBracuk Sorry for the confusion if any, but I am trying to do exactly opposite of what you got. After typing the 5 chars in the first box, when the user gets to the next box(onkeyup shall do this I guess), the script/query should determine whether the value entered in the first box was valid or not.

Comment: You want to use a different event than onkeyup.  onchange or onblur might to the trick.  Write a function that alerts "hello" and call it with different events to see what they do.

Answer (score 1):

The issue at the moment is that all your "validation" data is only available serverside. Ideally you want to use javascript for the validation on the form fields as the user types. This way you can do the validation client side without having to make additional calls to the server.

There are few ways to achieve what you want to do:

One (possibly a bit hacky) way to do this is to use Coldfusion to populate a javascript array in your page:

```
<script>
    var myArray = <cfoutput>#serializeJson(OrgIndexArray)#</cfoutput>;

    //use javascript to validate the input by checking the cfinput value with the array.
    //assuming you have jquery:
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.classOfYourInputHere').on('keyup',function(){
            if ($.inArray( $this.val(), arr ))
            {
                //do something
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Alternatively you can create an API of sorts, that will allow you to do an ajax request to a coldfusion `.cfc` to retrieve the array data in javascript and then you would proceed similar to the above.

Please note that this is **not tested** in anyway, but it hopefully should help you in the right direction.